# Getting vars from $.get ajax call in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, function, callback, get

I know there are a LOT of threads on this.. but I suck bad at ajax and cannot for the life of me interpret the answers.

```
var loadUrl = "lib/php/ajax.php";

$.ajaxSetup ({ cache: false });

$.get(loadUrl +  href, function(data)
{
    var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
    console.log(obj.commentCount, obj.fileName);            
});  console.log(obj.commentCount, obj.fileName); // this one doesn't work.
```

How do I get those variables outside of the function =/   i know i need to use some kind of callback function .. or something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The callback gets executed after the ajax call has finished. Your last `console.log()` statement is going to be called first, because the ajax request happens asynchronously. The other problem is that `obj` belongs to the scope of the callback, which makes it unavailable on the outside. If you declare it outside of the callback, it'll be available but still unusable because of the first problem. It is going to be empty, until the ajax call has finished. What is the problem with doing the work in the callback?

Comment: this makes sense.  and thats what i ended up doing.  i did the work in the callback

Answer (score 2):

You can't for two reasons:

1. The code after the $.get is run instantly. The code inside the function is only run after the ajax response returns
2. The var obj is created inside the scope of the inner function so is not accessible outside.

The only way you can get this to work is to declare obj outside of the ajax request, assign the value inside the function and also set the ajax request to not be asyncronous (See [jquery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)) Although this kinda defeats the point of using ajax and will block the site until the result comes back.

Comment: I've turned async to false works just fine but im guessing i shouldnt get in the habit of doing that?  not 100% what the difference between that value being true or false is..

Comment: If it's false, nothing else on the page will happen until the ajax response is returned. If this takes a long time the browser might appear to freeze. The best thing is to make good use of the callback function to run the code that relies on the ajax result.

Answer (score -1):

Declare `var obj` first before, outside the function, then you can set it = to the data inside, and reference it outside after.

```
var loadUrl = "lib/php/ajax.php";
var obj = "";

$.ajaxSetup ({ cache: false });

$.get(loadUrl +  href, function(data)
{
    obj = $.parseJSON(data);
    console.log(obj.commentCount, obj.fileName);            
});
console.log(obj.commentCount, obj.fileName);
```

Comment: this still executes the second console.log before the $.get function is called =/

Comment: This won't work as the 2nd 'console.log(obj.commentCount, obj.fileName);' will be run before the ajax response is returned so obj won't have been set.

Comment: Why call console.log outside and inside on the same data? What's the purpose? Maybe I could help more with more explanation of intended purpose of calling the same data twice.

Answer (score -1):

```
var loadUrl = "lib/php/ajax.php";

function processAjaxResponse(obj)
{
  console.log(obj.commentCount, obj.fileName);
};

$.ajaxSetup ({ cache: false });

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    url: loadUrl +  href,
    success: function(data) {
       processAjaxResponse(data);
   }
});
```

Comment: This won't work as the 2nd 'console.log(obj.commentCount, obj.fileName);' will be run before the ajax response is returned so obj won't have been set.

Comment: this example still calls the second console.log before the first =(

Comment: i see what you did there.. thats interesting.  you push it out to a different function.  pretty funky.

Comment: This is still pretty much exactly the same as it was before, only it's calling a named function instead of an anonymous one. The external obj variable still has no value.

Comment: @Richard, yeah that obj is now useless (i'll edit it out). This is the best way to do it in terms of practise; it's best not polluting the global variable space when you can avoid it.